# Update in Firebase deleting other entries

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I am trying to enter a number of shifts under their date. This is working fine for the 19-01 but then when I try to enter the 20-01 that saves and deletes the entry of the 19-01.

Anyone know what the problem is and why it can't allow me to have more that one tree?

```
//ROSTERS SAVING 
//ROSTERS FOR MONDAYS
$(function Monday(){

  // CREATE A REFERENCE TO FIREBASE
  var dateMondayRef = new Firebase('https://shiftsapp.firebaseio.com/roster');

  // REGISTER DOM ELEMENTS
  var date1Field = $('#date1Input');
  var emp1put1Field = $('#emp1Input1');
  var enter1Field = $('#enter1');

  // LISTEN FOR KEYPRESS EVENT
  enter1Field.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      //FIELD VALUES
      var dateMonday = date1Field.val();
      var emp1put1 = emp1put1Field.val();
      var enter1 = enter1Field.val();

      //SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD
      var obj1 = {};
      obj1[dateMonday] = {
        emp1:emp1put1,
      }

      dateMondayRef.set(obj1);
      enter1Field.val('');
    }
  });

});

$(function Tuesday(){

  // CREATE A REFERENCE TO FIREBASE
  var dateTuesdayRef = new Firebase('https://shiftsapp.firebaseio.com/roster');

  // REGISTER DOM ELEMENTS
  var date2Field = $('#date2Input');
  var emp1put2Field = $('#emp1Input2');
  var enter2Field = $('#enter2');

  // LISTEN FOR KEYPRESS EVENT
  enter2Field.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      //FIELD VALUES
      var dateTuesday = date2Field.val();
      var emp1put2 = emp1put2Field.val();
      var enter2 = enter2Field.val();

      //SAVE DATA TO FIREBASE AND EMPTY FIELD
      var obj = {};
      obj[dateTuesday] = {
        emp1:emp1put2
      }

      dateTuesdayRef.set(obj);
      enter2Field.val('');
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you use Firebase's `set` method instead of `update` on the same ref (your `dateMondayRef` and `dateTuesdayRef` both point to the same Firebase node).

As described [in the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html), `set` will

> write or **replace** data

In other words, when you call `set` on your ref, you instruct firebase to write at this location (or replace any data that might be stored there with) the object you pass as an argument.

You can either use `update` on this ref (but that would preserve any child key that was present at `roster/$dateMonday` but that is not included in your new object) or grab a reference to your `dateMonday` node, and call `set` on that.

```
dateMondayRef.update(obj1)
dateTuesdayRef.update(obj2)
// or
dateMondayRef.child(dateMonday).set({emp1: ...})
dateTuesdayRef.child(dateTuesday).set({emp1: ...})
```

Comment: neither of these are working, the database still deletes the previous one

Comment: are you using one of these techniques in both your `Monday` and `Tuesday` functions ? I've edited my example to make it more explicit.